# Auto submit Google Form via google Forms API and Google App scripts

Tags: javascript, django, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want users to answer google form quizzes through a third-party app. I want to set a timer to quiz and auto submit the Google form after the time limit exceeds. Is there a way to do via using Google Forms API & Google App scripts?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Pleae add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can achieve this without involving Google Forms. Google does not allow modifying the form itself (at the time of writing this).
Since Google Sheets is where we can analyse the results, you could try populating the submissions from the third-party app to a Sheet.

1. Create a Google Sheet bound App Script
2. Make the App Script a web App using `doGet()` or `doPost()`
3. Make a script function to append a row to the sheet upon receiving data to the Web App endpoint.

There is a `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('quiz').appendRow()` method

Refer to [Google App Script Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)